# Help with left align?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations, vertical-alignment, amsmath

I was trying to left align this equation by using code

```
$$\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
E_\theta(L(\delta_1(X)) &=& E_\theta[(1-\frac{b}{a+X^2}) X-\theta]^2\nonnumber\\
                        &=&E_\theta[Y-\frac{b}{a+(Y+\theta)^2}(Y+\theta)]^2\nonnumber\\
                         &=& n-2bE\frac{Y(Y+\theta)}{a+(Y+\theta)^2}+b^2E\frac{(Y+\theta)^2}{[a+(Y+\theta)^2]^2}\nonnumber\\
                         &<&n-2bE\frac{Y(Y+\theta)^2-b/2}{a+(Y+\theta)^2} \label{eq:21}\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
```

However, it turns out it's still right aligned and it is labelled (1) instead of (2.1)

My preamble is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you indent the code by four spaces, as I did in my edit, it is rendered with colored syntax.

Comment: Regarding your use of `$$`, see [Why is `\[` …`\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Comment: It seems like you're using the older `eqnarray` notation for alignment. Use only one ampersand `&` to the left of the binary operator/relation to mark the appropriate alignment.

Comment: You mean to replace $=$ by $=?

Comment: Yep, this solved the left align issue. However, I still couldn't get label (2.1). Any ideas?

Comment: Replace `&=&` by `&=`...

Comment: What does `2` in `(2.1)` represent? The section? If so, perhaps adding `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}` to your document preamble might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're making several errors.

1. `$$` should never be used in LaTeX (see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to))
2. Just `equation` is sufficient to get an equation number
3. Lines in `aligned` are never numbered by themselves
4. The syntax is `<left hand side> &= <right hand side>`
5. There is no `\nonnumber` command; it is `\nonumber`, but in this case it's not necessary
6. The label should be outside the inner `aligned`
7. The `amsmath` package should be loaded only once.

In the example I used `\lipsum` to provide some mock text and show the alignment.

More important is the correct usage of `\left` and `\right` around big fractions.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for this example

\begin{document}

\section{A new section}

\lipsum*[3]
\begin{equation}\label{eq:21}
\begin{aligned}
E_\theta(L(\delta_1(X))
&= E_\theta\left((1-\frac{b}{a+X^2}) X-\theta\right)^2 \\
&=E_\theta\left(Y-\frac{b}{a+(Y+\theta)^2}(Y+\theta)\right)^2 \\
&= n-2bE\frac{Y(Y+\theta)}{a+(Y+\theta)^2}+b^2E\frac{(Y+\theta)^2}{[a+(Y+\theta)^2]^2}\\
&<n-2bE\frac{Y(Y+\theta)^2-b/2}{a+(Y+\theta)^2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

several problems here ...

- if you use `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` you shouldn't use `$$`.  (besides, `\[ ... \]` should be used instead of `$$` if you do want an unnumbered equation.)
- `\nonumber` (not `\nonnumber`) isn't needed if you're using `aligned`.  since `aligned` "groups" all the lines within it, any appearance there of `\nonumber` will suppress the equation number.
- the extra `&` following the `=` or `<` is what is forcing everything on the right-hand side to the right.  for `aligned` you should use only one `&`, *before* the sign of relation.  the extra `&` is the eqnarray convention; the single `&` is the proper method for the structures provided by `amsmath` (where `aligned` is defined).
- move the label *outside* the `aligned`; it belongs at the `equation` level.  this won't affect whether or not the equation number is printed, but it makes more sense to someone else reading the input code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear on what you mean when you say left aligned, but here's my attempt. Also, I wasn't clear if you wanted to explicitly number the equation, like I've done below, or if you want the equations to follow section numbers.

See the [wiki book](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics) for some more explanation on alignment and equation numbering.

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
E_\theta(L(\delta_1(X)) &= E_\theta[(1-\frac{b}{a+X^2}) X-\theta]^2 \\
                        &=E_\theta[Y-\frac{b}{a+(Y+\theta)^2}(Y+\theta)]^2 \\
                         &= n-2bE\frac{Y(Y+\theta)}{a+(Y+\theta)^2}+b^2E\frac{(Y+\theta)^2}{[a+(Y+\theta)^2]^2} \\
                         &<n-2bE\frac{Y(Y+\theta)^2-b/2}{a+(Y+\theta)^2} \label{eq:21} \tag{2.1}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```